# Bootstrap few glyphicons are not showing

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I go to the site https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/ I can choose from different glyphicons.

The problem is that the icons on the bottom are not working. For example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- showing -->
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-random color-blue"></i></span>

<!-- not showing -->
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal"></i></span>
```

Below the bootstrap and jquery version I use in my asp.net (vb) project: 
Bootstrap: 3.3.7 
jquery: 3.2.1

Is there a way that I can add those glyphicons? 
According to the bootstrap site those not showing icons should work for 3.3.7

Comment: Hi! Can you provide an example in jsbin or codepen?

Comment: I added an executable snippet to your question which appears to work fine. Check your own version to ensure there's no errors in the console, or CSS rules which are overriding Bootstrap

Comment: The snippet appears to work fine. Maybe try including the CSS in the header and the JS in the footer?

Comment: Thanks all for your quick reply.
I checked it at jsbin and it is working indeed

I checked my bootstrap.css and saw that those glyphicons are not added also in the file glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg

Can I add them manually or do I need to update my bootstrap version?

Comment: A tip: use http://fontawesome.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it was my own fault.

After checking, the bootstrap version file was 3.0.0.
Did an update to 3.3.7 and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the bootstrap CSS, you can see that the icons are actually a icon font.

```
@font-face{
    font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src:url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot);
    src:url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix) 
    .......
}
```

If you want these icons to show, you have to make sure that these fonts can be found by your browser.